# How/where can I manage Authentication at SecurityContext in pre-authentation Scenario

Tags: spring-security

I wonder how/where can I manage Authentication at SecurityContext in pre-authentation Scenario.

I am using spring security 2.x to implement pre-authentation Scenario in my project. now, it patially work.

After user login by pre-authentation process, they can be authrozied with relevant roles, and are able to acecess resources which defined in security:filter.

e.g.

```
<security:filter-invocation-definition-source lowercase-comparisons="true" path-type="ant">
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/resource/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

In a some controller, I want to check principal in security content.

```
public abstract class AbstractUserAuthenticationController extends AbstractController
{
    protected boolean isAuthenticated(String userName)
    {   
        Object obj = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); // where issue come up
```

But SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() always return null.

In addition, I also can not use secuiry tag in jsp to check if user has relative roles

```
<security:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">

 no role found

</security:authorize>
```

Below shows the "filterChainProxy" I am using.

```
    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
      <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
        <value>
          CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
          PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT 
          /*subscri*=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,subscribeExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor      
          /**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter,logoutFilter,rememberMeProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor
        </value>
      </property>
    </bean>


 <bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
     <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" />
  </bean>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="demo.project.security.auth.RsaAuthenticationUserDetailsService" >
   <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</bean>

<bean id="j2eePreAuthFilter" class="demo.project.security.filter.AutoLoginFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
  <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</bean>
```

I think I need to set Authentication to SecurityContext in somewhere, But I do not know where/where.

What I am missing? Can anyone provide me some clues?

Thanks！

Ian

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SecurityContextHolder.setContext` method to store your `SecurityContext` prior to getting it back.

The simplest way for doing this is just `SecurityContextHolder.setContext(new SecurityContextImpl())`.